# Using Ansible set_fact to create a dictionary from register results systemctl

Tags: dictionary, ansible

In Ansible I've used register to save the results of a task in the variable services. 
It has this structure:

```
"stdout_lines": [
            "arp-ethers.service                          \u001b[1;31mdisabled\u001b[0m",
            "auditd.service                              \u001b[1;32menabled \u001b[0m",
            "autovt@.service                             \u001b[1;31mdisabled\u001b[0m",
            "blk-availability.service                    \u001b[1;31mdisabled\u001b[0m"]
```

and I would like to receive this:

```
{
    "arp-ethers.service": "disabled",
    "auditd.service": "enabled",
    "autovt@.service": "disabled",
    "blk-availability.service":"disabled"
}
```

I'd like to use a subsequent set_fact task to generate a new variable with a dictionary, but I'm going round in circles with no luck so far.

```
- name: Collect all services for SYSTEMD
  raw: systemctl list-unit-files --type=service  --no-pager -l  --no-legend`
  register: services
  changed_when: false

- debug:
    var: services

- debug:
    msg:  "{{ item.split()[0]|to_json }} : {{ item.split()[1]|to_json }}"
  with_items:
     - "{{ services.stdout_lines }}"

- name: Populate fact list_services for SYSTEMD
  set_fact:
    cacheable: yes
    list_services: "{{ list_services|default({}) | combine ( {item.split()[0]|to_json: item.split()[1]|to_json} ) }}"
  with_items: "{{ services.stdout_lines }}"
```

This return :

```
 FAILED! => {"msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got u'arp-ethers.service                          \\x1b[1;31mdisabled\\x1b[0m\\r\\nauditd.service                              \\x1b[1;32menabled \\x1b[0m\\r\\nautovt@.service                             \\x1b[1;31mdisabled\\x1b[0m\\r\\nblk-availability.service                    \\x1b[1;31mdisabled\\x1b[0m\\r\\n'"}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to switch `list-unit-files` into [json output using `--output=json`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html#%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20json%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20) (yes, that's a link to the journalctl man page, because [the `systemctl` one links there](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#-o))

roughly like this, although I didn't test it:

```
- name: Collect all services for SYSTEMD
  raw: systemctl --output=json list-unit-files --type=service
  register: services_json
  changed_when: false

- set_fact:
    services: '{{ services_json.stdout | from_json }}'
```

Comment: sorry but in this machine return, 
{"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({u'list_services': u'{{ services3.stdout | from_json }}', u'cacheable': True}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: No JSON object could be decoded\n\n

when execute : 
systemctl --output=json list-unit-files --type=service  --no-pager -l  --no-legend 
does not return json. 

[link](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/83)

Answer (score 0):

Use [service_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html#service-facts-return-service-state-information-as-fact-data). For example

```
    - service_facts:
    - set_fact:
        dict_services: "{{ dict(ansible_facts.services|
                                dict2items|
                                json_query('[].[key, value.status]')) }}"
```